# Cannot hide redactor strikethrough button when table plugin is enabled

Tags: redactor, table

I am trying to set a Redactor field so that it only shows the table button, though no matter what I do... the strikethrough button appears, it looks like the correct name is `strike` though doesn't appear to work (tried multiple variations) though no luck. Are there any suggestions on how to hide it? Here is my redactor config:

```
{
  "buttonsHide": ["link", "lists", "strikethrough", "Strikethrough", "strike", "italic", "bold", "format", "html"],
  "plugins": ["table"]
}
```

Comment: Are you selecting the right config in Settings → Fields → yourRedactorField **Redactor Config** and is it a different one than *Default*?

Comment: Yep! The other buttons in the `buttonsHide` array are being hidden, so the config is working... just not with the strikethrough button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name to use to hide the Strikethrough button is `deleted`.

Comment: Of course it is...  Thanks @Oli . I can confirm this works.